# Why are my random numbers not so random?

Tags: java, random

```
int totalRecs = getTotalRecs(); // returns '13'
int MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP = 10;
Random rand = new Random();
int start = (totalRecs > Utl.MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP) ? rand.nextInt(totalRecs-Utl.MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP) : 0;
results = this.getNewRecs(filter, start, start+1);
```

I'm using this random number logic to retrieve records from the database based on their table row offset (`start` up to `start+1`).

But for some reason **it keeps repeating the same numbers: `start` value of 0 and `start` value of 3**.

I tried seeding the `Random` object but it made no difference:

```
long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
rand.setSeed(seed);
```

Comment: What is Utl.MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP?  Likely the issue isn't rand.nextInt but rather your inputs are constraining it to a tiny subset of possible ints.

Comment: Something very odd happening. If totalRecs is really 13 then you shouldn't be getting 3 (as you're passing 3 to nextInt and that is the exclusive upper limit). Can you try printing the value of totalRecs and check  it's what you think? Why are you using Utl.MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP rather than the MAX)RECS_PER_LOOKUP you just set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rand.nextInt(n)` method returns a value between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive).

In your code, if `totalRecs` is 13, and `Utl.MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP` is 10 (I am assuming this one based on the `MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP` value in your code snippet, but I may be wrong), then this code:

```
rand.nextInt(totalRecs-Utl.MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP);
```

should return a random number between 0 and 2.

I am not sure if this is what you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your inputs are valid.

Via debug compare values of

totalRecs  Utl.MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP  & start on the same iteration.

You are calling

```
rand.nextInt(totalRecs-Utl.MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP)
```

The only way you should "always" be getting 0 is if totalRecs = Utl.MAX_RECS_PER_LOOKUP
However if the difference is only 1 then you will get back 0 or 1 randomly.

Answer (score -1):

You could try java.security.SecureRandom

It seems to be a good alternative, and it inherits from java.util.Random